# Merge multiple database snapshots into one database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, snapshot

I'm trying to figure out how to merge database snapshots into one database. For each month I am creating a database snapshot so the data will be static and represent a specific month. The reason I want the data to be static is because the Power BI report only needs to show the data of how it was at the moment of taking the snapshot.

Because I am not able to merge the monthly database snapshots into one database, I have to duplicate the Power BI report and change the database name(of the specific database snapshot) I have to query on to extract the dataset.

Is it possible to combine multiple database snapshots(e.g. snapshot_jan17 and snapshot_feb17) into one database so I can access the snapshotted data from a single Power BI report and add an identifier to each table that is representing the specific snapshot month(for filtering purposes)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potentially relevant to your problem. Regarding

> I have to duplicate the Power BI report and change the database name

In short, you can have "Empty query" variables for server/database names, use these in your queries, and then change your data source in a single place, rather than in every single query of your report.

---

#### Preventing data source string duplication

By default, when data is imported to the PowerBI Desktop, each table or query stores data source details separately, even if they use the same data source.

This makes it tedious, for example, to change the source database of an entire PowerBI report - which requires changing each query source parameter individually.

There is a way to simplify this, described [here](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2015/11/09/avoiding-duplication-of-database-connection-information-in-power-bi/).

---

1. Import your data as you normally would. Example: data source type - SQL server,
   server name - `localhost`,
   database - `test1`,
   tables - `table1`, `table2`.
2. In query editor, add two blank queries: "Get Data" -> "Blank Query",
   `serverName` with value `= "localhost"`,
   `databaseName` with value `= "test1"`.
   [image]
3. For each table on the "Queries" pane on the left, select "Source" in "Query Settings" on the right, then substitute server and database names with parameters created in the step 2.
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
4. Now when you need to update your connection string, change `serverName` or `databaseName` and refresh data.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the-box functionality for this.  I doubt there are any 3rd party tools, because of the way snapshot dbs manage their storage, in the file system.

You could roll your own solution, perhaps using [SSIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services).  The trade off is increased file storage.

Power BI loves [dimensionally modelled star schema's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema).  If you do implement a custom reporting db, you should consider this while designing.